# Android: downloading large files from server

Tags: android, http, download

In my android application I am downloading large files from server(1GB) using the following:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setReadTimeout(7000);
connection.connect();
input = connection.getInputStream();
output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Android/" + fileName, true);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;

int total = 0;
while (count = input.read(data)) > 0) {
total = total + count;
output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

The code works well. But sometimes the downloaded file gets corrupted and I don't know why! Is there a mechanism or algorithm, library ... to guarantee a successful download 100%? Please help, I don't know what to do! I don't want to use checksum to check if the file is ok and if not then download it again! I want a solution to detect the problem while downloading and fix the corrupted portion instantly!

Comment: `new byte[1024];`. Your buffer is much to small. Make it a 100 times bigger at least.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ok I make the buffer larger and lets see if the problem goes away.